# Make part of a string value for React Element bold

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the variable defined in my file:

```
var text = `The start of string ${<b>{this.state.isTrue ? 'Bolded' : 'Also Bolded'</b>} the end of string.`
```

This string is being passed to a React element:

```
<span>{text}</span>
```

I want the texts `Bolded` or `Also Bolded` to be bolded when the component renders, but depending on the way I am trying to pass the string, I either get `[object Object]` instead or `<b>Bolded</b>`.

The only way that I found working was this:

```
var text = <React.Fragment>The start of string {<b>{this.state.isTrue ? 'Bolded' : 'Also Bolded'</b>} the end of string.</React.Fragment>
```

But this seems rather verbose and sometimes string is plain and does not contain any placeholders, so using React element to wrap it seems unnecessary. Plus, I would like to be able to store the value in the database and when retrieved it should be interpolated in a way that would show the text that is marked as bolded - bolded.

**Question:** Is there any way to have the text between `<b></b>` within a string bolded when the component gets rendered?

Comment: What do you mean by place holder?

Comment: @ArupRakshit parts of the template string that get interpolated on execution: `text ${placeholder} text`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achive what you are trying to accomplish using the [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html?#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) props.

Look at the code below:

```js
function App(props) {
  const text = {
    __html: `The start of string <b>${
      props.isTrue ? "Bolded" : "Also Bolded"
    } </b> the end of string.`
  };

  return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={text} />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App isTrue={true} />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I suppose it might be dangerous to use it?

Comment: @Eduard Why? :) Because the name suggest... :) Well read the doc I linked too. It is something we store html in DB, and when it needs to be rendered, this is the only option.. and I am sure React does sanitization, XSS check..

Comment: @Eduard yes.. but sometimes there is need to do.. so React gives you a control.

Comment: React does not do XSS checks, you need to do that manually by using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss

Comment: Only use if you know what is the string, in that case you could just do it manually, so, it's useless as the content will obviously be user generated hence shouldn't be trusted.