# Div not converting text between <b> </b> html tags to real bold text

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tags, bold

I am dynamically creating one string in javascript and then sending that to render inside reactjs component. For Eg:

First creating string and then rendering

```
let displayText = "<b>Name: </b>" + this.name;
then 
render() {
   return (
 <div class={test-str}>
          {displayText}
        </div>
)

}
```

But the issue is  that on page, it is renering it as `"<b>Name: </b> TestName"`

How to get those `<b>` get converted to bold?

FYI:- I am creating this string inside some other Util library. Outside of the component and calling back the util which is returning this string.

Comment: check out [react fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Comment: FYI: then read about [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 3):

you can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML like this:

```
render() {
   return (
        <div class={test-str}>
          <div  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: displayText}} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

or you can use JSX like this:

```
let displayText = (<b> Name: </b> {this.name});
```

**JSX** allows us to write HTML in React. JSX makes it easier to write and add HTML in React

Answer (score 1):

you must do this: `***(<span><b>Name: </b> {this.name}</span>)***`, it will render tags.
use () for render tags and make sure that you have main container like ()

Comment: I don't have issue rendering name value, It is not rendering Name: in bold but instead it is  rendering <b> tags also

Comment: Did you see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030205/make-part-of-a-string-value-for-react-element-bold

Comment: Here you are saying that make a string like this:

let displayText = (<span><b>Name: </b> {this.name}</span>)  

which is not acceptable. because I have to first dynamically generate the string and use that string inside render. I hope you get it.